HTTP error 404: Tag not found
Objective
Find the hidden tag for this puzzle.
Clues

[3 found] An insect steals a vowel from their relative (3)
[2 found] A viscous substance advances a website at the final (4)
[1 found] A stoner says their favorite dish is chicken on rice (10)
[1 found] A wild dog rings a bell; ring it again (5)
[1 found] A body part of mine (3)
[404 NOT FOUND]
[1 found] A machine breaker voices a Russian citadel at the beginning (7)
[1 found] A humanoid set an explosion; the debris hit Bob (6)
[1 found] A demon emoji (3)
[3 found] A jam, initially just elastic, like liquid, yeah (5)
[4 found] The etymology for a metal element starts to knock out bold texts (6)
[1 found] A thief has a peer – launch them with an explosion (10)
[3 found] A shapeshifter starts speaking into a miniature microphone (5)
[3 found] Another thief in her youth, like an insect (5)
[5 found] A humanoid seeks for cans; they're hidden (3)
[3 found] A creature hidden upward hides a copier, certainly (7)
[404 NOT FOUND]
[3 found] A vermin misplaces an art (3)
[2 found] An arthropod writes a red Ψ for detonation (6)
[1 found] A lurker below sets an explosion per part (7)
[3 found] An equine asks for one maize (7)
[5 found] A swirl replaces a vowel from a facet (6)
[4 found] An invertebrate codes something malicious (4)
[1 found] A leg breaker hides a box, and... (3)
[1 found] A color, or... (6)
[1 found] [REDACTED] (5)

My first puzzle involving cryptic-clues – Enjoy!


 1. [3 found] An insect steals a vowel from their relative (3) = ANT (AUNT - U)
 2. [2 found] A viscous substance advances a website at the final (4) = BLOB (???)
 3. [1 found] A stoner says their favorite dish is chicken on rice (10) = COCKATRICE (COCK (chicken) + AT (on) + RICE)
 4. [1 found] A wild dog rings a bell; ring it again (5) = DINGO (DING ('rings a bell') + O ('ring'))
 5. [1 found] A body part of mine (3) = EYE (???)
 6. [404 NOT FOUND]
 7. [1 found] A machine breaker voices a Russian citadel at the beginning (7) = GREMLIN (KREMLIN (russian citadel) change first letter)
 8. [1 found] A humanoid set an explosion; the debris hit Bob (6) = HOBBIT (anagram of HITBOB)
 9. [1 found] A demon emoji (3) = IMP (???)
 10. [3 found] A jam, initially just elastic, like liquid, yeah (5) = JELLY (J(ust) E(lastic) L(ike) L(iquid) Y(eah))
 11. [4 found] The etymology for a metal element starts to knock out bold texts (6) = KOBOLD (K(nock) O(out) + BOLD) (etymology of Cobalt)
 12. [1 found] A thief has a peer – launch them with an explosion (10) = LEPRECHAUN (anagram of PEERLAUNCH)
 13. [3 found] A shapeshifter starts speaking into a miniature microphone (5) = MIMIC (MI(niature) + MIC(rophone))
 14. [3 found] Another thief in her youth, like an insect (5) = NYMPH (???)
 15. [5 found] A humanoid seeks for cans; they're hidden (3) = ORC ((f)ORC(ans))
 16. [3 found] A creature hidden upward hides a copier, certainly (7) = PIERCER ((co)PIERCER(ertainly))
 17. [404 NOT FOUND]
 18. [3 found] A vermin misplaces an art (3) = RAT (anagram of ART)
 19. [2 found] An arthropod writes a red Ψ for detonation (6) = SPIDER (anagram of REDPSI)
 20. [1 found] A lurker below sets an explosion per part (7) = TRAPPER (anagram of PERPART)
 21. [3 found] An equine asks for one maize (7) = UNICORN (UNI (one) + CORN (maize))
 22. [5 found] A swirl replaces a vowel from a facet (6) = VORTEX (VERTEX, E -> O)
 23. [4 found] An invertebrate codes something malicious (4) = WORM (???)
 24. [1 found] A leg breaker hides a box, and... (3) = XAN ((bo)XAN(d))
 25. [1 found] A color, or... (6) = YELLOW
 26. [1 found] [REDACTED] (5) = ZRUTY (???)


 Each "found" number is the number of NetHack monsters containing the corresponding word that fall under the corresponding monster letter category (ex: ANT finds 3 becuase 3 monsters under monster classification "a" have the word ANT: Giant ant, Soldier ant, Fire ant). Therefore, the missing tag is video-games.


I suspect, given what you've found, it might be this one...

@Stiv ah, I didn't notice that was a tag...

Presumably, gur jrofvgr vf n oybt
